# Can not login to SharePoint 2013 using IE 10

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, internet-explorer, security-token-service

Currently when I try to access our intranet using IE 10 , I will be promoted with the windows security dialog box, and after entering my username and password for three times , I will receive a white page. While if I try to access the SharePoint using Firefox or chrome it will work well.
Baring in mind that I have added my intranet URL to the trusted site and to the local site on IE.
Can anyone please advice ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to add the Domain to Compatibility Mode?

Comment: can you adivce more on this ?

Comment: Sometimes you have a strange behavior with your IE in combination with OS and SharePoint. Than the compatibility view can help.
http://corypeters.net/2012/10/problems-with-ie10-and-sharepoint/

Comment: i tried adding sharepoint.com & dynamics.com to the Compatibility View Settings, but nothing chnaged

Comment: Also make sure that you don't use 64 Bit Version of IE 10

Comment: but i am using 64 bit version ,, should i use only 32 bit ?

Comment: Yes. You have to! You'll find it in /Program Files (86)/Internet Explorer

Comment: well i am not sure, if Sharepoint 2013 can not be accessed using IE10 64 bit. i can not force all our employees to use 32 bit only !!!!

Comment: OK. But it is official from Microsoft that there are problems with 64 Bit :)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: this link does not mentione any thing about SP support for the 64 bit version

Comment: Search for "only 32-bit versions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following workaround. It might help you.

Open Internet Explorer 10
Press ALT
Click Tools > Compatibility View Settings
In the “Add this website” box add the following sites using the Add button
sharepoint.com
dynamics.com
Click Close
Now when you refresh the page you should see the Browser Mode correctly represented as Browser Mode “IE10 Compat View” and Document Mode “IE8 Standards”.

Comment: i tried your steps but nothing changed, i added sharepoint.com & dynamics.com to the Compatibility View Settings.

Comment: Add you site as well and close the browser .. Then start again

Comment: but i do not want to display my site in compatibility view,, i will loose many layouts and some pages will be unstructured .... i can not force our employees to run our intranet on compatibility view !!

Comment: also we have a staging server containing basically the same SharePoint site collection and version, and i can access it without even typing my username and password,, but for the live version i am having this problem .